# Working with UITableView inside UICollectionViewCell(Mimic Google Places Bottom Scrolling List)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to mimic google places bottom scrolling list. Please refer the images below for better understanding

**Google Places Bottom Scrolling List UI**
[image: Google Places Bottom Scrolling List UI]

**My UI**
[image: My UI]

I have created a horizontal scrolling UICollectionView, with each UICollectionViewCell containing a UITableView

I have an array that contains data related to each tableview. I am loading the data into the tableView during UICollectionViewDelegate Method [cellForRow at: indexPath:] by using **indexPath.row** as my arrayIndex. But I see some tableViews have same data.

I would like to know how do I keep track of each UICollectionViewCell and load only related data into that tableView inside UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use collectionView prefetching.

```
if (collectionView.responds(to: #selector(setter:
UICollectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled))) {

    collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false

}
```

I suggest you do not reuse tableViews.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
"YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let tableView = tableViews[indexPath.item]
    tableView.data = dataArray[indexPath.item];

    tableView.removeFromSuperview()
    cell.contentView .addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.frame = cell.contentView.bounds

    return cell

}
```